# Rule whose second prerequisite depends on first prerequisite match

Tags: makefile

I would like to express the following rule in a Makefile:

> For any values of `file1` and `file2`, if `file1.txt` and `file1_file2.py` exist, then I can generate `file2.txt` by running:
>
> `python file1_file2.py file1.txt > file2.txt`

I start by writing the "easy part", the pattern matching for the target:

```
%.txt : file1_%.py file1.txt
    python file1_%.py file1.txt > $@
```

But now to make it fully generic, the second prerequisite must change depending on the full name of the first prerequisite - the one that contains the `%` pattern match.

Is there any way to express this?

Comment: There is no way to create such a pattern rule.  If you can determine the set of such files (say, by using `$(wildcard ...)` than you can auto-generate the appropriate rules using looping / `eval` / etc.  But there's no way to simply create a generic rule that has those attributes.

Comment: Closest I can think of is having a conditional in the recipe, like: `(test -f f1.txt && test -f f2.txt) || exit 0`

Comment: Your problem is not fully specified, I think. What if you have `file1.txt`, `file1_file2.py`, `file3.txt` and `file3_file2.py`? What do you do? Build `file2.txt` with `file1.txt` and `file1_file2.py` or with `file3.txt` and `file3_file2.py`?